# TSQL count number of declared characters in string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Ive got the following script, which should count the number of characters declared in @Char that is found in @password but its not working, can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
Declare @password as varchar(25), @Result int = 0,  @Char varchar(max), @index BigInt = 0

Set @password = 'su8cd023m6!$^j3'

Set @Char = '%[a-z]%'

DECLARE @passwordLen int = len(@password)

SET @index = CHARINDEX(@password, @Char, @index)
While @index > 0
BEGIN
    SET @Result = @Result + 1;
    SET @index = CHARINDEX(@password, @Char, @index + @passwordLen)
END

Print @Result
```

The above should return 6 as there are 6 alpha characters in @password

Comment: Could you please provide a reference showing that `CHARINDEX()` accepts wild cards in an `expressionToSearch`?

Comment: I havn't got one, so guessing your gonna tell me it doesnt and that that is where im first going wrong?

Comment: This is Transact SQL. Which DB are you using?

Comment: @Jeffrey as in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Correct, sorry for not giving the full name

Comment: Your questions states the answer should be `6` because `there are 6 alpha characters in @password`.  But your script indicates that you're searching for `%[0-9]%`, which are *numeric* characters.  Coincidentally, there are both `6` numeric characters in `@password` *and* `6` alpha characters in `@password`.  *Which are you looking for?*

Comment: @Siyual, corrected the question now, its alpha, but someone below has given a suitable answer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @password as varchar(25), @Result int = 0,  @Char varchar(max), @index BigInt = 0

Set @password = 'su8cd023m6!$^j3'

  WHILE PATINDEX('%[^A-z]%',@password)>0
        SET @password = STUFF(@password,PATINDEX('%[^A-z]%',@password),1,'') 

Set @Result = Len(@password)

Print @password
Print @Result
```

Answer (score 0):

[Using Numbers table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable)..

```
declare @str varchar(max)
set @str='su8cd023m6!$^j3'

;With cte
as
(

select 
case when isnumeric (substring(@str,n,1)) =1 then 1 else 0 end as val
from dbo.numbers
where n<len(@str)
)
select count(*) from cte where val=1
```

**Output:**
6

you also can use TRY_CONVERT(From SQL 2012),since IsNumeric tendS to show some special characters as 1 in similar way..

```
;With cte
as
(

select 
case when try_convert(int,substring(@str,n,1)) is null  then 0 else 1 end as val
from dbo.numbers
where n<len(@str)
)
select count(*) from cte where val=1
```

Comment: see this link :http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable